# PHPExcel is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

With the help of this below link 
http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework/

I have taken the reference but it won't work. File is downloading but the error am getting while opening the file "The file your are trying acb.xls is in a different format than specified by file extension. Verifiy that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.do you want to open the file now ?"

when i used to open the file then some text is populating  "PK2¥yJG’D²Xð[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa ©QÄ¿i!£ÒKµy3ÜJ<§œZ1½0?YÙL%zV "

I have google it and trying to sort out the above problem since last 3 hours but it won't work for me and also try with MAC OS & now am trying on windows OS but the same error is populating.

Comment: What Writer are you using? That stream of data looks like the beginning of an `xlsx` file (Excel2007 Writer) rather than an `xls` file

Comment: Writer using "Excel5" & tried with 2007 too but it won't work.

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and check for leading/trailing whitespace characters, or a BOM header, or any plaintext error messages or html markup that might be included in the file from something else in your code

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your PHP and library encoding. Use UTF-8 encoding. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for comment!!, Where i have to set the UTF-8

Comment: Just added the these two line of code ob_end_clean(); ob_start(); and remove the spacing where php tag ends and..... Here we go !!!!!

Comment: Use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
and you can change php.ini for utf-8 encoding.